# Strange Problem with inlining equations $..$

Tags: amsmath

I am experiencing this strange issue with my latex build system. I use MacTex 2017, and I have cleaned all old scripts and reinstalled based on [the instructions](http://www.tug.org/mactex/uninstalling.html). Here is my issue:`$f(x)$` will show up without parenthesizes. And for things like `nicefrac` in $..$ the `\` is ignored: `$MR_{LLC} = \nicefrac{a}{b}$` is shown as `MR_LLC = ab`.

I tried to use `\(..\)` but did not solve the issue.

On the other hand, I used texlive on ubuntu 16.04 to build the pdf, and non of these problems happened.

Does anyone has an idea what might be wrong?

Here is a sample code (it is a big document, so most packages are required):

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}

\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % This is Times font
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[topline=false,rightline=false]{leftbot}

\colorlet{light-gray}{gray!20}


\usepackage[hang,flushmargin,bottom,multiple]{footmisc}

% custom
\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{red}\textbf{TODO}: #1}}
\newcommand{\needcite}[0]{{\color{red}[NeedCite]}}
\newcommand{\needref}[0]{{\color{purple}NeedRef}}
\newcommand{\lifeng}[1]{{\color{blue}\textbf{Lifeng}: #1}}


\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}


\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,
   justification=justified,
   format=plain]{caption}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  language=C++,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  stepnumber=1,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{black},
  captionpos=b,
  mathescape=true
}



% Copyright
%\setcopyright{none}
%\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
%\setcopyright{rightsretained}
%\setcopyright{usgov}
%\setcopyright{usgovmixed}
%\setcopyright{cagov}
%\setcopyright{cagovmixed}


% DOI
%\acmDOI{}
%
%% ISBN
%\acmISBN{}

%Conference
\acmYear{2017}

%\copyrightyear{2017}

%\acmPrice{15.00}

\acmJournal{TACO}

\setcitestyle{numbers,sort&compress}

\begin{document}

$f(x)$

$\nicefrac{a}{b}$



\end{document}
```

Shows as:

[image]

And here is output (I use Texpad as front end):

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory=/var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp root.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./root.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acmart/acmart.cls
Document Class: acmart 2017/05/14 v1.39 Typesetting articles for Association of Computing Machinery
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/totpages/totpages.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ncctools/manyfoot.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ncctools/nccfoots.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftex/glyphtounicode.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cmap/cmap.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mweights/mweights.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/LinLibertine_I.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inconsolata/zi4.sty `inconsolata-zi4' v1.112, 2017/01/04 Text macros for Inconsolata (msharpe)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxmath.sty `newtxmath' v1.518, 2017/02/12 Math macros based on txfonts (msharpe) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)<<t1.cmap>>)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty Excluding comment 'comment') Excluding comment 'CCSXML' (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty) Special comment 'acks' Include comment 'screenonly' Excluding comment 'printonly' Include comment 'anonsuppress' (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/T1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/units/nicefrac.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty

Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015
(fixltx2e)                All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
(fixltx2e)                See the latexrelease package for details.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/balance.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathptmx.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/flushend.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/indentfirst.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tablefootnote/tablefootnote.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xifthen/xifthen.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifmtarg/ifmtarg.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/threeparttable/threeparttable.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator-language-mappings.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/placeins/placeins.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/needspace/needspace.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/md-frame-0.mdf)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty

LaTeX Warning: Command \@footnotemark  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.sty
Document Style algorithmicx 1.2 - a greatly improved `algorithmic' style
)
Document Style - pseudocode environments for use with the `algorithmicx' style
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty) (/var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/omlnxlmi.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxexa.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/lmsntxsy.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/lmxntxexx.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ptm.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ztmcm.fd)<<ot1.cmap>> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omlztmcm.fd)<<oml.cmap>> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omsztmcm.fd)<<oms.cmap>> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omxztmcm.fd)<<omx.cmap>> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxmia.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxsym.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxsyc.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-ptm.cfg) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty)) (/var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.out) (/var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.out) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-basic-dictionary/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/OT1LinuxBiolinumT-TLF.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inconsolata/ot1zi4.fd) [1.1{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information){/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on /var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.pdf (1 page, 14233 bytes).
SyncTeX written on /var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.log.


/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory=/var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp root.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./root.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acmart/acmart.cls
Document Class: acmart 2017/05/14 v1.39 Typesetting articles for Association of Computing Machinery
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/totpages/totpages.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ncctools/manyfoot.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ncctools/nccfoots.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftex/glyphtounicode.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cmap/cmap.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mweights/mweights.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/LinLibertine_I.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inconsolata/zi4.sty `inconsolata-zi4' v1.112, 2017/01/04 Text macros for Inconsolata (msharpe)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxmath.sty `newtxmath' v1.518, 2017/02/12 Math macros based on txfonts (msharpe) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)<<t1.cmap>>)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty Excluding comment 'comment') Excluding comment 'CCSXML' (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty) Special comment 'acks' Include comment 'screenonly' Excluding comment 'printonly' Include comment 'anonsuppress' (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/T1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/units/nicefrac.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty

Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015
(fixltx2e)                All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
(fixltx2e)                See the latexrelease package for details.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/balance.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathptmx.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/flushend.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/indentfirst.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tablefootnote/tablefootnote.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xifthen/xifthen.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifmtarg/ifmtarg.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/threeparttable/threeparttable.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator-language-mappings.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/placeins/placeins.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/needspace/needspace.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/md-frame-0.mdf)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty

LaTeX Warning: Command \@footnotemark  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.sty
Document Style algorithmicx 1.2 - a greatly improved `algorithmic' style
)
Document Style - pseudocode environments for use with the `algorithmicx' style
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty) (/var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/omlnxlmi.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxexa.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/lmsntxsy.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/lmxntxexx.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ptm.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ztmcm.fd)<<ot1.cmap>> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omlztmcm.fd)<<oml.cmap>> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omsztmcm.fd)<<oms.cmap>> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omxztmcm.fd)<<omx.cmap>> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxmia.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxsym.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxsyc.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-ptm.cfg) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty)) (/var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.out) (/var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.out) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-basic-dictionary/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/OT1LinuxBiolinumT-TLF.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inconsolata/ot1zi4.fd) [1.1{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information){/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on /var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.pdf (1 page, 14233 bytes).
SyncTeX written on /var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /var/folders/5f/9jwcvzb578gb03bjdjgr3wrw0000gn/T/workspace_temporary_path_107202387273792/.texpadtmp/root.log.
```

Comment: please show a small complete document that shows the problem, and the log file you get on mactex from that file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle apparently using mathptmx package was the issue.

Comment: Not really:  mathptmx will work on mactex the same as ubuntu texlive, if you have not installed the fonts you should have had an error not just missing brackets and fractions not working.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have updated the question.

Comment: Don't use mathptmx with this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unrelated to differences between texlive on OS X and ubuntu, I get the same in cygwin, the log will show

```
Missing character: There is no � in font zptmcm7y!
Missing character: There is no � in font zptmcm7y!
Missing character: There is no � in font zptmcm7y!
```

The mathptmx setup is not compatible with the packages used.

`mathptmx` is anyway rather old, a newer times-like setup is `newtxmath`:

```
\RequirePackage[full]{textcomp}
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}

\usepackage{nicefrac}
%\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{balance}
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % This is Times font
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[topline=false,rightline=false]{leftbot}

\colorlet{light-gray}{gray!20}


\usepackage[hang,flushmargin,bottom,multiple]{footmisc}

% custom
\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{red}\textbf{TODO}: #1}}
\newcommand{\needcite}[0]{{\color{red}[NeedCite]}}
\newcommand{\needref}[0]{{\color{purple}NeedRef}}
\newcommand{\lifeng}[1]{{\color{blue}\textbf{Lifeng}: #1}}


\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}


\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,
   justification=justified,
   format=plain]{caption}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  language=C++,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  stepnumber=1,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{black},
  captionpos=b,
  mathescape=true
}



% Copyright
%\setcopyright{none}
%\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
%\setcopyright{rightsretained}
%\setcopyright{usgov}
%\setcopyright{usgovmixed}
%\setcopyright{cagov}
%\setcopyright{cagovmixed}


% DOI
%\acmDOI{}
%
%% ISBN
%\acmISBN{}

%Conference
\acmYear{2017}

%\copyrightyear{2017}

%\acmPrice{15.00}

\acmJournal{TACO}

\setcitestyle{numbers,sort&compress}

\begin{document}

$f(x)$

$\nicefrac{a}{b}$



\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, ubuntu official texlive is also old. I guess that was why I did not see the error there. Thanks for the help. @DavidCarlisle